# How to extract text and add link automatically

Tags: php, javascript, extract

I have a website, and I want to do this feature, when a post is loading I want to extract some word and add link automatically.

For example: if I access a post via mydomain.com/my-post and in its content have words : "MyWord" , I want to extract that word and replace it with link like MyWord.

How can I do this by using js or php ?

Thanks !

Comment: Your problem is related to scraping. Find an API that can do this.

Comment: can you recommend me some ?

Comment: Questions asking for code need to include your attempts, and clearly stating how those attempts didn't work.